# keep a single line in multiline javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

I have a identical line in multiline

[image: multiline in var url]

Response of ajax request with HTLM for my many articles

```
function handleResponse(results, status){

    // delete all (old) markers
    deleteMarkers();

    $('#loader').addClass('hidden');

    if(status === 'success' || status === '200'){

        $(results.html).find("article").each(function(thisIs) {

            // created one marker for some articles
            createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng($("#lat", this).val(), $("#lng", this).val()));
        });

        /* Microtemplating MustacheJs : Show all articles when it work is finish */
        $("#result").empty().html(results.html).removeClass('hidden');
```

When the user click on modal "I Want"

```
        $('.iWant').click(function(event) {

            /* ---- DELETE OLD CONTENT ---- */

            // deleted disabled for button 'send'
            $('#sendMessage').attr('disabled', false);

            // deleted error message
            $('.modal-body').find('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
            $('.modal-body').find('.help-block').remove();

            /* delete old content in textarea */
            $("#messageSend").val('');

            /* ------------------ THE END ------------------ */

            // Stop the loading 
            event.preventDefault();
            // catch the url for Ajax Request
            url = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#iWantModal').modal('show');
        });
```

When the user click for to send his message

```
        $('#sendMessage').click(function(){
            // blocked the button send
            $('#sendMessage').attr('disabled', true);

            $('.modal-body').find('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
            $('.modal-body').find('.help-block').remove();

            // show the multiple line
            console.log(url);

            // call ajax (API)
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    messageSend: $('#messageSend').val(),
                    emailSend: $('#emailSend').val(),
                    name: $('#userName').text(),
                    userId: $('#userId').text()
                },
                beforeSend: function(request) {
                    return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("input[name='_token']").val());
                },
                success: function() {

                    // Close the modal
                    $('#iWantModal').modal('hide'); 

                    $("#messageSend").val('');
                },
                error: function( json ){

                    $('#sendMessage').attr('disabled', false);
                    $.each(json.responseJSON.errors, function(index, value){

                        // show error message
                        if (value.length != 0){
                            $("#" + index).parent('div').addClass('has-error');
                            $("#" + index).after('<span class="help-block"><span class="error">' + value + '</span></span>');
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

How to keep the first/single line ?

Comment: It's easy if you can explain explain explain more :)

Comment: Please explain more...

Comment: I'm sorry, i have edited

Answer (score 1):

What you've shown is a screenshot from the Chrome devtools console. It's showing that code has logged the same exact text three times.

There's nothing you can do in your code to change how Chrome handles that. Either only log that text once, or add something unique to it if you want the devtools to show each of the three instances.